# Getting JAX-WS to generate code with parameters that have namespaces?

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, jax-ws, wsimport

I have a WSDL and I have gotten wsimport to generate good code for it. And the code runs. And the "hello" operation (with no parameters) does just fine.

But now I am calling a "CreateSomething" operation. My server code is complaining that no parameters are being sent in the request. But I log it out in my server code and I see it right there....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <S:Body>
    <ns2:ABCDEFGRequest
      xmlns:ns2="http://ray.com:55555/cgi-bin/WebObjects/App.woa/wa/abcsoap">
      <AAA>999</AAA>
      <BBB>Dept 999</BBB>
      <CCC>Dept 999 password</CCC>
      <DDD>abcNextTest</DDD>
    </ns2:ABCDEFGRequest>
  </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

Hey, that looks fine to me! So, what up? And when I manually create a request, that works.

So, the problem is that

```
      <AAA>999</AAA>
```

should be

```
      <ns2:AAA>999</ns2:AAA>
```

But of course I am not creating the request. The JAX-WS-generated code is. So, how do I tell it that the parameter needs to be in the namespace also? This seems kind of basic.

The slice of my WSDL that contains this operation is below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<wsdl:definitions
    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
    xmlns:tns="http://__HOST__/cgi-bin/WebObjects/__APP__.woa/wa/abcsoap"
    targetNamespace="http://__HOST__/cgi-bin/WebObjects/__APP__.woa/wa/abcsoap">

    <wsdl:types>

        <xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://__HOST__/cgi-bin/WebObjects/__APP__.woa/wa/abcsoap">

            <xsd:element name="ABCDEFGRequest"> 
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:all>

                        <xsd:element name="AAA">
                            <xsd:simpleType>
                                <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                    <xsd:length value="3" />
                                </xsd:restriction>
                            </xsd:simpleType>
                        </xsd:element>

                        <xsd:element name="BBB">
                            <xsd:simpleType>
                                <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                    <xsd:minLength value="1" />
                                    <xsd:maxLength value="40" />
                                </xsd:restriction>
                            </xsd:simpleType>
                        </xsd:element>

                        <xsd:element name="CCC">
                            <xsd:simpleType>
                                <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                    <xsd:minLength value="1" />
                                    <xsd:maxLength value="40" />
                                </xsd:restriction>
                            </xsd:simpleType>
                        </xsd:element>

                        <xsd:element name="DDD">
                            <xsd:simpleType>
                                <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                    <xsd:minLength value="1" />
                                    <xsd:maxLength value="8" />
                                </xsd:restriction>
                            </xsd:simpleType>
                        </xsd:element>

                    </xsd:all>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>

            <xsd:element name="ABCDEFGResponse">
                 <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:all>
                        <xsd:element name="AAA">
                            <xsd:simpleType>
                                <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                    <xsd:length value="3" />
                                </xsd:restriction>
                            </xsd:simpleType>
                        </xsd:element>
                    </xsd:all>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>

        </xsd:schema>
    </wsdl:types>

    <wsdl:message name="ABCDEFGRequestMessage">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:ABCDEFGRequest"/>
    </wsdl:message>

    <wsdl:message name="ABCDEFGResponseMessage">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:ABCDEFGResponse"/>
    </wsdl:message>

    <wsdl:portType name="LMSPortType">
        <wsdl:operation name="ABCDEFG">
            <wsdl:input name="ABCDEFGRequestMessage" message="tns:ABCDEFGRequestMessage"/>
            <wsdl:output name="ABCDEFGResponseMessage" message="tns:ABCDEFGResponseMessage"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>

    <wsdl:binding name="LMSBinding" type="tns:LMSPortType">

        <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>

        <wsdl:operation name="ABCDEFG">
            <soap:operation soapAction="ABCDEFG"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>

    </wsdl:binding>

    <wsdl:service name="LMSService">

        <wsdl:port name="LMSPort" binding="tns:LMSBinding">
            <soap:address location="http://__HOST__/cgi-bin/WebObjects/__APP__.woa/wa/abcsoap"/>
        </wsdl:port>

    </wsdl:service>

</wsdl:definitions>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow. Apache is really good at putting out lots of documentation. Lots. So, here I am, eyes bleeding, having read through a bunch of the JAX-WS alphabet soup and the answer was very simple.

I found this by checking out the source for JAX-WS. Really. And in there I found:

```
svn co http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/axis/axis2/java/core/trunk/
modules/samples/wsdl/perf.wsdl
```

And so I see that I need to go to the top of my WSDL and change:

```
    <xsd:schema
         xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
         targetNamespace="http://__HOST__/cgi-bin/WebObjects/__APP__.woa/wa/abcsoap">
```

to:

```
    <xsd:schema
         elementFormDefault="qualified"
         xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
         targetNamespace="http://__HOST__/cgi-bin/WebObjects/__APP__.woa/wa/abcsoap">
```

And that is all.

Wow. Given the behavior, this might be the default, yes? O well.